# Как работает деструктурирующее присваивание?

Tags: javascript

Объясните как работает алгоритм деструктурирующего присваивания. Я решил проверить поведение, но не могу понять, почему консоль выдает именно такие результаты.

Прежде чем задавать вопрос, я ознакомлялся со всеми источниками, кроме самой спецификации, ибо она сложная для восприятия, и я не знаю английский.

Источники: [ES6: Реструктуризующее присваивание](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-destructuring), [Деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring), [Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

**1**

```js
var {a,aa,...aaa} = [2, 4, 23];

console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

**2**

```js
var [a,aa,...aaa] = {a:2, aa: 4, aaa: 23};

console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

UPD: Воспользовался [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA3hIDS3hAdKk6IF8IF4IG0IAmBAFgSIGYIBdAbgCgHRJCAjBNjlVLt23NAhsAXCWGiI5CZKpY6QA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0), может он как - то поможет.

Comment: Ты где видел подобные идентификаторы [a,aa,...aaa] и {a,aa,...aaa}? это что за конструкция?

Comment: @Air важно то как ведет себя интерпретатор и по какому алгоритму.

Comment: Виталик, я не понимаю, что ты именно хочешь...   Ты объясни, чего хочешь добиться?

Comment: @Air Объясните как работает алгоритм деструктурирующего присваивания.

Comment: Виталик, благодарю за вопрос, это ECMA6...  Благодаря тебе щас сижу читаю))))  много интересно...

Comment: советую https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_ddM5gevVU&list=PLqHlAwsJRxAOpWPtj2T6HhSzX-lKmKV2q&index=5

Comment: @Air это другой оператор, который не имеет значение в контексте моего вопроса. [ES6: Операторы Spread и Rest](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-spread-rest)

Comment: Вы в объект хотите записать массив, и наоборот, попробуйте так `var [a,aa,...aaa] = [2, 4, 23, 144];`

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163574/grundy-room

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> var {a,aa,...aaa} = [2, 4, 23];

```js
var src = [2, 4, 23];
var a, aa, aaa;

a = src.a;

aa = src.aa;

aaa = {};
for (var key in src)
  if (key !== 'a' && key !== 'aa' && src.hasOwnProperty(key))
    aaa[key] = src[key];

console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

В таком поведении можно убедиться следующим образом:

```js
var {a, b, ...rest} = {
  __proto__: {
    b: 2, // декомпозиция в переменную
    d: 4  // исчезает, т. е. НЕ попадает в rest
  },
  a: 1, // декомпозиция в переменную
  c: 3  // попадает в rest
}

console.log(a, b, rest)
```

Если хочется потрошить массив как объект, то можно использовать декомпозицию с переименованием - ведь числа не могут быть иментами переменных, но обращаю внимание, что в `aaa` всё равно объект, а не массив:

```js
var { 0:a, 1:aa, ...aaa } = [2, 4, 23];
console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

> var [a,aa,...aaa] = {a:2, aa: 4, aaa: 23};

```js
var src = {a:2, aa: 4, aaa: 23};
var a, aa, aaa;

var i = 0;
aaa = [];
for (var x of src) { // Упадёт прямо на of
  switch (i++) {
    case 0:
      a = x;
      break;
    case 1:
      aa = x;
      break;
    default:
      aaa.push(x);
  }
}

console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

Через `[]` можно деструктуризировать только итерируемые объекты:

```js
var src = { *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield 2; yield 4; yield 23; } };
var a, aa, aaa;

var i = 0;
aaa = [];
for (var x of src) {
  switch (i++) {
    case 0:
      a = x;
      break;
    case 1:
      aa = x;
      break;
    default:
      aaa.push(x);
  }
}

console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

PS: А вообще лучше всё делать по-человечески:

```js
var [a, aa, ...aaa] = [2, 4, 23];
console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

```js
var {a, aa, ...aaa} = {a:2, aa: 4, aaa: 23};
console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

Comment: То поведение которое вы сымитировали, соответствует алгоритму в спецификации, если да, то все понятно. Будьте добры, поясните как работает этот тип данных `var src = { *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield 2; yield 4; yield 23; } };`, а то я с ним сталкивался, но не особо понимаю эту сущность. И воспользуясь случаем, хотел бы у вас спросить, как работают встроенные(native code) функции в `js`, если они написаны на C++, но в среде браузера работаю на ура, но некоторые не возможно cимитировать в контексте `js` по типу `call`, `apply`.

Comment: Думаю, должно соответствовать, но я не сверял со спецификацией при ответе. Кстати, там ещё вложенная деструктуризация и значения по умолчанию есть, так что рассмотрена только часть, затронутая в твоём вопросе. А генераторы - это довольно большая тема, по которой можно задать отдельный вопрос. Про си++ вообще не понял вопроса.

Comment: Есть стандартные методы в `js` такие как `apply`, `call`, но их съимитировать невозможно, так как допуска к контексту нету и написать свой метод не возможно, ибо js написан на C++. Вопрос заключается в том, как эти методы работаю, если их повторить нельзя, но при этом они работают в браузере.

Comment: _Кстати, там ещё вложенная деструктуризация и значения по умолчанию есть_. Можете более детальней разъяснить, а то не могу представить как это выглядит.

Comment: `var { a, b: {c, d, ...x}, e: [f, g, ...y], ...z } = { a:1, b:{c:2,d:3,u:-1,v:-2}, e:[4,5,-3,-4], w:{q:32}};
console.log(a,c,d,x,f,g,y,z);`

Comment: я все что можно прочел по поводу деструктуризации. мне просто было интересно как себя будет вести с другой массив с объектом и наоборот.

Answer (score 3):

В обоих случаях поведение непонятное так как вы объект пытаетесь пропихнуть в массив и наоборот.

В документации смотрим синтаксис:

```
var a, b, rest;
[a, b] = [1, 2];
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2

[a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
console.log(rest); // [3, 4, 5]

({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2

({a, b, ...rest} = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4});
```

Тут нету варианта деструктуризации массива в объект и наоборот. Справа и слева во всех примерах одинаковые скобочки, то есть массив деструктурируется в массив, а объект в объект.

Вот конструкция которая работает как и предполагается, обратите снимание на скобочки:

```js
var [a,aa,...aaa] = [2, 4, 23, 144];
console.log(a, aa, aaa);
```

**Пункт 1.** Запускаем babel и получаем код:

```
var _ref = [2, 4, 23],
a = _ref.a,
aa = _ref.aa,
aaa = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["a", "aa"]);
```

В `a` мы кладём `ref.a` так как _ref  это массив то `ref.a` не задан. Тоже самое с `aa`.
Теперь смотрим `aaa`,в него мы кладём все значения кроме `a` и `aa`, но так как `a` и `aa` не заданы, то на выходе получаем все три значения.

Подводим итог, в `a` и `aa` ничего не кладётся, так как справа у массива нету переменной с названием `a` и `aa`, а в `aaa` мы кладём всё что осталось.

Comment: Вот как ваш ответ отвечает на мой вопрос? Я в источниках указал 3 статьи на эту тему и прекрасно знаю как нужно использовать деструктуризацию. Моя задача понять механизм, что в следствии ответит на вопрос почему консоль выводит именно такие логи. Я осознано написал такие примеры, но вместо того, что бы объяснить что происходит, мне пишут как нужно правильно использовать деструктуризацию. Прежде чем отвечать, прочтите внимательно вопрос.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный что вы знаете, мне не известно из вопроса. Я добавил в ответ разъяснение сделанное из babel компиляции кода.

Comment: читайте внимательно вопрос. В источниках я указал статьи, и там даже для самого отсталого по примерам будет наглядно понятно как работает деструктуризация. Раз я знаю что такое babel, то это что - то говорит.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный и что это повод меня минусовать? Я вам помочь пытаюсь... и да, я написал по первому пункту почему работает именно так.

Comment: это не ответ на мой вопрос. отредактируйте или напишите новый ответ который будет соответствовать вопросу и я с удовольствием поменяю оценку.

Comment: _"Тут нету варианта деструктуризации массива в объект и наоборот."_ - это утверждение неверное, хотя в остальном ответ хороший.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я очень вам благодарен, но вы мне пытается объяснить саму деструктуризацию, а не что под капотом. Ни в коем случаи я не хотел вас обидеть, просто я не могу одобрить ответ, которые не как не относиться к моему вопросу. Надеюсь вы меня понял и еще раз спасибо за труд.

Answer (score 1):

Я, прочитав даже одну статью на MDN, понял суть.
Для массивов: 
Не важно, как был получен массив(многих запутают переменни и функции в примерах на MDN), вся суть в то, что присваивание происходит в том же порядке, что переменные в первом массиве:

```
var [a, b, c]=[vl1,vl2,vl3]
a->vl1
b->vl2
c->vl3
```

Если в правом массиве больше значений, чем в левом, то лишние просто не используются, либо помещаются в переменную с оператором spread (...)

```
var [a, b, c, ...d]=[vl1,vl2,vl3,vl4,vl5]
a->vl1
b->vl2
c->vl3
d->[vl4,vl5]
```

Для объектов:

Практически тоже самое, только значение помещается в переменные по ключам свойств:

```
var {a,c,b}={a:1,b:2,c:3}
a->1
b->2
c->3
```

---

```
var {a,c,b,...w}={a:1,b:2,c:3,d:10,e:12}
a->1
b->2
c->3
w->{d:10,e:12}
```

В обоих случаях лишние переменные в левом массиве будут объявлены со значением undefined