# Что это означает.. function func({value: usevalue }){}

Tags: javascript

Что это означает..

```
function func({value: usevalue }){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это **[Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)** объекта.

При простом применении будет вот так:

```
let user = {      
  name: 'test',
  value: 200
};

let {name: n, value : usevalue } = user;

alert(n);       // test
alert(usevalue); // 200
```

Та же самая конструкция в аргументах функции автоматически разбирает прилетевший объект на отдельные составляющие и уже внутри неё будет существовать переменная `usevalue` со значением из объекта, у которого имя ключа было `value`

```js
function func({ value: usevalue }){
    console.log(usevalue);
} 

let obj = {value: 'test'};
func(obj);
```

---

Ещё можно о деструктуризации почитать на **[ruSO - Как работает деструктурирующее присваивание?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759151/191482)**, по ссылке выше и в целом в сети интернет)