# Атрибут value в фигурных скобках

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой кусок кода. Что означает {value}? Правильно ли я понимаю, что после такого обозначения value может использоваться как переменная и просто как атрибут в другой части кода?

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector(".textarea");

textArea.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    main.innerHTML = marked(value);
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: "равильно ли я понимаю, что после такого обозначения value может использоваться как переменная и просто как атрибут в другой части кода?" --- как переменная, не как атрибут. Но да, может использоваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это **[Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)** объекта.

Простое применении будет вот так:

```
let user = {      
  name: 'test',
  value: 200
};

let {name: n, value : usevalue } = user;

alert(n);       // test
alert(usevalue); // 200
```

Происходит автоматическое разбиение объекта на отдельные составляющие и уже далее будет существовать переменная `usevalue` со значением из объекта, у которого имя ключа было `value`. В вашем случае из объекта `e.target` достаётся значение по ключу `value` и складывается в одноимённую переменную (если не указывать имя "выходящей" переменной, то она будет совпадать с тем, что указано в фигурных скобках)

Ещё можно о деструктуризации почитать на **[ruSO - Как работает деструктурирующее присваивание?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759151/191482)**